# Dynamic Columns into ui:define

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a data table in an xhtml with "ui:insert" space...
In another xhtml i use ui:define to add some columns... the problem is that i have dynamic columns to insert..
i've already tryed with a4j:repeat, ui:repeat, c:foreach and rich:columns...

```
<rich:columns value="#{entity.dadosAdicionais}" var="col" >
    <h:outputText value="#{col.valor}" escape="false" />
    <h:outputText value="#{col.nome}" />
</rich:columns>
```

someone knows whats the problem with ui and rich components?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try like this.

```
<rich:columns value="#{entity.dadosAdicionais}" var="col"  index="index">

<f:facet name="header">    
        <h:outputText value="#{col.valor}" />    
    </f:facet>    

   <h:outputText value="#{model[index].model}" />
</rich:columns>
```

value= the modelValue for column.

Comment: its not working.. i mean... the problem is not the outputText... he dont shows de column name... even if i put the value without outputtext.. its like he is not recognizes the rich:columns value... but just before the rich columns i ask him to show the size of the dadosAdicionas attribute and it shows my list correctly...

Comment: Is the entity.dadosAdicionais the list of ColumnValues?

Comment: did you try this link? http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html

Comment: yeah... i've used exactly as that link shows... but not worked.. maybe there is something problem with datatable using ui component... dunno...